# Opening terminal in current directory

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc

I am attempting to set up the behavior described in the title. For reference, there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673836/how-to-open-terminal-in-current-directory) which solve this for emacs. I however use DWM/ST and Zsh.

The solutions I have clumsily tried to come um with include modifying the .zshrc file in the with the following lined:

```
cd $pwd
```

I have realized this does not make sense as the path displayed by this instance of pwd will in fact be the path in which the terminal itself is opened, which is $HOME. Maybe the solution is messing with ST, but I have not had any ideas of how to do do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, this is entirely independent of the shell you are using, or even whether you start a shell session in a terminal window. Most terminal emulators should provide a way to set the working directory for whatever process is being started.

Comment: @Lara : Unless you explicitly set the variable `pwd`, it will be empty and hence `cd` will place you into your home directory. The variable which is automatically set to the working directory is named `PWD`. But as chepner said, this approach is flawed anyway. Actually I can not infer from your question what exactly you want to achieve, i.e. what you want to type into your command line, and what effect it should have. I am also missing a description, which operating system you are running. Linux? And you are using [this](https://st.suckless.org/) terminal, right?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the terminal emulator that you're using: for instance

```
 $lxterminal --working-directory=./
```

Works for zsh in my manjaro distribution.

in Ubuntu i might use:

```
 $x-terminal-emulator ./
```